# Exception when migrating custom User in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to create a custom User for my app and followed exactly the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) from the documentation with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.MyUser'` in my `settings.py`. However, when I make a new database, delete all the migrations folders and run the `python manage.py migrate` again, it gives me the exception like this

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 173, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 47, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 132, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.concrete_apps
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 180, in concrete_apps
    self.apps = StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models, ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.render_multiple(list(models.values()) + self.real_models)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 277, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 559, in render
    body,
  File "/Users/bubuzzz/Projects/python/apps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 153, in __new__
    raise TypeError("%s cannot proxy the swapped model '%s'." % (name, base_meta.swapped))
TypeError: Customer cannot proxy the swapped model 'core.MyUser'.
```

I am not sure why there is a migrations script for the `customer` there, since in my app, I used to have the `Customer` model as well, though I deleted it already.

Then, I created a new django project to test and try to run the migration. Surprisingly, I also see those customer migration steps, but it run successfully.

```
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_customer... OK
  Applying auth.0010_delete_customer... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

In short, how can I create the custom User in Django 1.10 ? Example code can be viewed in here https://github.com/bubuzzz/django-customer-swap-exception

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete your migration folder. If you do that, django won't make migrations for you. Create migrations folder in your core app, create an empty `__init__.py` file inside it, remove your db.sqlite3 file, run ./manage.py makemigrations, and then migrate should work perfectly.

Comment: i am not sure with the previous django, but with the 1.10,  i delete the migrations folder, django will create it again. The mirations script work still `auth.0009_customer` like you see in my question

Comment: please let me see full traceback

Comment: ok, i think there is something wrong with my environment. I created a new project and make the new app, it will give the customer migrations script as well https://i.imgsafe.org/782ac2d079.png. It better to delete the environment and do everything from scratch again

Comment: try use virtualenv if you are not using it.@Thai Tran

Comment: I think you have messed with your Virtualenv. Try creating a new one and test anew. There is no need to start a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi Pourfar's answer is correct.If you want to know more details

> By running makemigrations, you’re telling Django that you’ve made some changes to your models (in this case, you’ve made new ones) and that you’d like the changes to be stored as a migration.
>
> Migrations are how Django stores changes to your models (and thus your database schema) - they’re just files on disk. You can read the migration for your new model if you like; it’s the file polls/migrations/0001_initial.py. Don’t worry, you’re not expected to read them every time Django makes one, but they’re designed to be human-editable in case you want to manually tweak how Django changes things.

Tell django which app you want to make migrations all fix your problem.It will auto create a folder call migrations keep your model's record.

```
python manage.py makemigrations core
```

Comment: Please check my comment on Mehdi 's answer. Please check my sample project to see the problem

Comment: @Thai Tran, I downloaded your code and ran on my computer, the folder will not auto create if you did not specific which app you want to make migrations.Delete your django_migrations table and file in migrations, then run python manage.py makemigrations core will work.

Comment: hmm, then it is weird. I just push the clean folder again with the migrations folder (I removed db already). `python manage.py makemigrations core` still give the exception. Which OS and django version are you using at this moment ?

Comment: I'm using latest django and osx, but I don't think this matter, did you remove the db.sqlite3?

Comment: What I did just `download your whole project`, then `delete the db.sqlite3`, then run `python manage.py makemigrations core`

Comment: hi Windsooon, i think it is the problem of my environment. Please check my comment on @Mehdi Pourfar